# How to do a Custom List in Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm working on an application that needs to have a Custom list in a fragment.
I try a lot of thing in vain... This is my best result:

**MainActivity.java** :

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_list);
        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null )
        {
            if(savedInstanceState != null)
                return;
        }
        ListFragment listFragment = new ListFragment();
        listFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, listFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

**stops.java**:

```
public class stops {
    private String name;
    private String destination;
    private String schedule;
    private int iconID;

    public stops(String name, String destination, String schedule, int iconID)
    {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.schedule = schedule;
        this.iconID = iconID;
    }
    public String getName(){ return name; }
    public String getDestination(){ return destination; }
    public String getSchedule(){ return schedule; }
    public int getIconID(){ return iconID; }
}
```

**ListFragment.java**:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListFragment extends Fragment{
    private List<stops> mystops = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<stops> adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        populateStopList();
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        adapter = new myListAdapter(context);
        ListView list = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.stopsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        return V;
    }

    private void populateStopList() {
        mystops.add(new stops("Corum", "Odysseum", "5min", R.drawable.green_tram));
        mystops.add(new stops("Corum", "Mosson", "2min", R.drawable.orange_tram));
        mystops.add(new stops("Corum", "Saint-Jean de Vedas", "1min", R.drawable.red_tram));
    }

    private class myListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<stops> {
        public myListAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.item_view, mystops);
            add(new stops("Corum", "Mosson", "2min", R.drawable.green_tram));
            populateStopList();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null)
                itemView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
            stops currentStop = mystops.get(position);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            imageView.setImageResource(currentStop.getIconID());
            TextView nameText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_nameTextView);
            nameText.setText(currentStop.getName());
            TextView destinationText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_destinationTextView);
            destinationText.setText(currentStop.getDestination());
            TextView timeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_timeTextView);
            timeText.setText(currentStop.getSchedule());
            return itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_list.xml**:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:   context="com.example.msa_m.listsstops.ListFragment"
    android:id= "@+id/fragment_container"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT DU LAYOUT FRAGMENT"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/stopsList"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

**item_view.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id ="@+id/my_list_item">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/green_bus"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:minHeight="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Nom de l&apos;arret"
        android:id="@+id/item_nameTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_icon" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Destination"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/item_destinationTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_nameTextView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_icon" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Temps"
        android:id="@+id/item_timeTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

But when I run it, this endless load with a ProgressBar in the middle of the screen...

Does someone can help me ?

Comment: See how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DizzyCode What the problem,  too much code ?

Comment: Yes, try to narrow down to where you think the problem is occurring.

Comment: I think Its probably because you forgot to call #notifyDataSetChanged(). From what I can see, your only modifying the underlying dataset, but not the list adapter. The progress circle should disappear when the adapter is notified of new data. If your using 'ArrayAdapter' you can also call 'add', 'remove' etc. on the adapter itself.

Comment: @tobs Sorry tobs but I'm kind of new in android dev'.. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: @Maregas No problem, of course ;). You have an array list with custom objects. And then you create your Adapter and pass your list. But the adapter cannot know your list has been created / edited etc. thats why you have to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged. That way you tell the adapter to "refresh" the list

Comment: @Maregas Because your using ArrayAdapter, you can call 'add(Object)' on the adapter, and it will automatically notify itself about the update

Comment: @tobs I maybe do something wrong but I try 'add(Object)' and/or to 'notifyDataSetChanged' but nothing changed, I always have the progress circle...

Comment: @Maregas Are you extending ListFragment? If so, be sure to call this.setAdapter

Comment: @Maregas If you dont, be sure to inflate (or create) your custom layout in onCreateView.

Comment: @tobs I extend Fragment so try to inflate, it's the same result..

Comment: @Maregas Could you please post your whole Fragment code in your question?

Comment: @tobs Here the full code !

Comment: @Maregas Ok thanks, give me a second, ill try it...

Comment: @Maregas looks like your code works fine for me :/

Comment: @tobs That's weird.. I just try to make again the projet and still loading.. :/

Comment: @tobs And I tried on a device and an emulator

Comment: @Maregas OK, i could you please be more specific? I'm not really able to understand your problem. Where do you create the loading circle?

Comment: @tobs Nowhere... it take the place of the list in the middle of the screen. But I did not implement the loading circle :/

Comment: @Maregas Congratulations, You've reached the weird part of android development :D

Comment: @tobs I can't talk on this chat, I have less than 20 reputation on Stack Overflow :/

Comment: @Maregas Uuups, sorry for that

Comment: @Maregas However, are you sure you do not extend ListFragment? Because this fragment shows a loading circle you described as long as the adapter is not set

Comment: @tobs If I'm sure ? I have the exact same code in my question, so I think I do not extend ListFragment, because I extend only "Fragment" in ListFragment.java

Comment: @Maregas I was not about to criticize you, copy & paste errors happened to me a lot of times. If you just extend Fragment, I cannot see where the loading bar could come from. I think this could only be some kind of layout misbehavior. One thing I noticed is that you inflate your layout twice: First in the activity and then in the fragment.

Comment: @tobs Excuse me, I did not want to seem aggressive :/ And I agree with you, I have some copy & paste errors in my question.. 
How I inflate in the activity ? And I'm suppose to inflate in the fragment no ?

Comment: @Maregas Activity and Fragments can manage their components independently from the UI of the other component. Your activity layout should (only) hold a container such as an empty FrameLayout with an id (for example @+id/fragmentContainer).This container is the used by the Fragment Manager to display the contents of the fragment. The Fragment however has its own UI provided by onCreateView

Comment: @tobs ok, but how can I use my custom adapter if I do not have a list ?

Comment: @Maregas In your case, I would inflate the layout with the list view in it in onCreateView like you did. You could create your Adapter instance in onCreate and finally set the adapter to the list in onViewCreated

Comment: I'll give a simple example in an answer, wait a sec..

Comment: @Maregas does it work now?

Comment: @tobs Thank you so much for all of this, your code totaly work ! :D

ps: my code work finely work to, I do not extend ListFragment **BUT** I import it in MainActivity.java:  
`import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since your code works fine for me, heres a modified version of your project.

Your Activity Layout could probably look like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, in your activity, you just inflate the activity layout and replace the container with your fragment:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListFragment listFragment = new ListFragment();
        listFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, listFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

And your fragment takes care of inflating the list ui and managing all the data:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment{
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<stops> adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayList<stops> mystops = new ArrayList<>();
        mystops.add(new stops("Corum", "Odysseum", "5min", R.drawable.green_tram));
        mystops.add(new stops("Corum", "Mosson", "2min", R.drawable.orange_tram));
        mystops.add(new stops("Corum", "Saint-Jean de Vedas", "1min", R.drawable.red_tram));

        adapter = new myListAdapter(getActivity(), mystops);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.stopsList);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private static class myListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<stops> {
        public myListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<stops> stopList) {
            super(context, R.layout.item_view, stopList);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null)
                itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);

            stops currentStop = getItem(position);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            imageView.setImageResource(currentStop.getIconID());
            TextView nameText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_nameTextView);
            nameText.setText(currentStop.getName());
            TextView destinationText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_destinationTextView);
            destinationText.setText(currentStop.getDestination());
            TextView timeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_timeTextView);
            timeText.setText(currentStop.getSchedule());

            return itemView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all of this, your code totaly work ! :D

ps: my code work finely work to, I do not extend ListFragment **BUT** I import it in MainActivity.java:  
`import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;`

Comment: @Maregas Oh yea, i see! I also did not recognize this :D I feel a bit embarrassed now ;) But I'm glad it works now. So go on and have fun with android !

Comment: Don't worry I feel more embarrassed ;)
Thank you again ! :D